# How can a 32bit CPU have an addressable memory size of 16TB?

Tags: operating-systems

Frequently, on a 32-bit CPU, each page-table entry is 4 bytes long, but that
size can vary as well.

A 32-bit entry can point to one of $2^{32}$ physical page frames.

If frame size is 4 KB (212), then a system with 4-byte entries can address $2^{44}$ bytes
(or 16 TB) of physical memory.

The above statement is taken from the book "Operating System Principles" by Galvin.

If all 32 bits in a 32-bit CPU are used to refer to pages , then we can have $2^{32}$ pages. But then no more bits will be left to point to memory inside a page of size $2^{12}$ bits since all 32-bits have been used up.

How can we thus say that $2^{44}$ bytes are addressable?

Comment: The extra 12 bits still must exist somewhere, they are just faked in a backwards-compatible way.

Comment: Had they not been faked the CPU could have accessed the memory faster, right? There wouldn't have been a need to store the bits part by part and then work on it.

Comment: Yes, which is one of the many reasons to go 64-bit. Also, usually PAE is limited to the OS and individual applications are still limited to 4 GB.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to why would someone want a 32bit CPU to be able to address more than 4GB of memory? Even if swapping is taken into account, won't that degrade the performance a lot?

Comment: The answer is that it was less work than going to 64-bit. And, yes, it was a complete disaster, requiring jumping through many hoops: https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $32$ bit page frame address acts as a base address and will be typically stored in an index register.

An individual machine code instruction (e.g. a branch instruction) will then contain a $12$ <s>byte</s> bit offset. The offset is added to the base address to create the complete $44$ <s>byte</s> bit address.

Comment: if we can store the intermediate addresses and then combine them later on to access the memory location then why do we stop at 32+12? Why not a 64bit page address and then a 12 bit offset?

Comment: There is nothing special about 32+12 bit addressing - its is just an example. A range of other memory management schemes (some of which are very complex) are described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit.